# Enable Swagger for Spring Boot application of v2.2.2. version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Spring boot sample Application of version v2.2.2.RELEASE, it serves 2 GET requests.
What version of swagger and swagger UI should I use, as the latest version of springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui is not supported in mentioned version of Spring Boot?